# How to get count of likes,shares,comment for individual post in facebook using open graph?

Tags: php, count, facebook-opengraph

I am using Open graph to get face-book page contents.The issue is that for **anonymous user** accessing the **graph result** its showing count of likes,shares and comments to be zero for each post. This is the code which I using for php.

```
$graph_url = "http://graph.facebook.com?id=".urlencode($feed_url);
 $content = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
 $account_url  = "https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=".$content->id."&format=json";
```

Here **content->id** is the **facebook page id** . Is there any way of getting count of likes,shares and comment for each post with anonymous user itself. Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to track social likes count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268969/how-to-track-social-likes-count)

Comment: @lin : I have used open graph method over here and also my question is for anonymous user accessing facebook page.

Comment: is my answer correct so? -> "Understood, need to create facebook app in-order to access all those share,likes,comment etc.."

Comment: Yes, but i cant able to get share count still ??

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot access private data as anonymous user. You need an access-token ([FB-oAuth](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth?locale=de_DE)) in case with a Facebook Application and [Users/Page/App permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2) to access private data.**

You can try it with fql or graph API. If you try to access "private" data. Make sure your created a facebook app before and unlock all user permissions you need to. Means, Stream Reading I think: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2. Without that permission, you cannot access private data.

Public example:
http://graph.facebook.com/386050065267_10153256675935268/comments?summary=true

```
SELECT like_info.like_count, comment_info.comment_count, share_count 
  FROM stream 
 WHERE post_id IN (
       SELECT concat(id,'_', substr("https://www.facebook.com/Macklemore/posts/10153256675935268", strpos("https://www.facebook.com/Macklemore/posts/10153256675935268", '/posts')+7, strlen("https://www.facebook.com/Macklemore/posts/10153256675935268"))) 
        FROM profile WHERE username IN (
             SELECT substr(url, strpos(url, 'facebook.com/')+13, strpos(url, '/posts')-strpos(url, 'facebook.com/')-13) 
               FROM object_url 
              WHERE url = "https://www.facebook.com/Macklemore/posts/10153256675935268"))
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "like_info": {
        "like_count": 5506
      }, 
      "comment_info": {
        "comment_count": 353
      }, 
      "share_count": 392
    }
  ]
}
```

Public data can be fetched like:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/386050065267_10153256675935268/comments?summary=true
```

or

```
https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/posts/POST_ID
```

Comment: As anonymous user,  I am able to get the contents of that page like title,description and images etc. Only Issue over there is that its showing zero for likes,shares and comments even though there are values in the facebook page for each post.

Comment: @Ram, shares, comments and even likes could be set as "private" data. If a user does not allow you to read out comments or a page does not allow you to read out "likes, etc." -> the privacy was set like that. You cannot access that data "anonymous". You need a access-token and almost Page/User permissions. Facebook is not 4chan ;). Cheers.

Comment: Understood, need to create facebook app in-order to access all those share,likes,comment etc..

Answer (score -1):

enter code here
  <?php 
  $fql = "SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count "; 
  $fql .= " FROM link_stat WHERE url = '$url'"; 
  $fqlURL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=" . urlencode($fql); // Facebook Response is in JSON $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$fqlURL); 
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
  $output = curl_exec($ch); 
  curl_close($ch); 
  $facebookdata json_decode($output);
  echo $facebookdata[0]->share_count;

echo "<br>";
  // facebook like count
  echo $facebookdata[0]->like_count;
  echo  " count <br>";
  // facebook comment count
  echo $facebookdata[0]->comment_count;
  It's very easy please try it